# May be I will do this. Or Maybe I will do this. Which is correct?

Tags: phrases

May be I will do this.

Or

Maybe I will do this.

Which of the two is correct?

And one of those is correct, then is there another context where the other form of Maybe/May be is used?

Comment: _Maybe_ as a single word means _perhaps_. There are many contexts in which _may_ and _be_ can be used in the same sentence. It _may be_ that you would be better to post on English Language Learners, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @KateBunting - "*Perhaps* it would be better to post on English Language Learners"

Comment: @KateBunting - Also shouldn't it be "It may be that you would be better *off* post*ing* on English Language Learners" - your construct doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: OK, you would _do_ better to post there. I didn't say you _couldn't_ use _maybe_ or _perhaps_ in that context.

Comment: @KateBunting - Anyway, I think you mostly answered my question. Whenever I want perhaps, I should use "Maybe". The other case is something "I may be late today" - where may & be are 2 separate words. If you put your original comment in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* as a single word means *perhaps*.

There are many contexts in which may and be can be used in the same sentence.

> This may be the last time I will go there.
>
> I may be wrong, but...